# Do all html nodes have a "getElementsBy" and getElementBy" version?

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

I'm learning vanilla js and something that keeps coming up is that I see some examples of code that say document.getElementBy... or document.getElement(s)By..., Is it the case that every html node has a corresponding js dom form where getElementBy refers to a single node and getElementsBy refers to a nodeList?

Comment: In short, yes, all elements have a `getElementsBy` and `getElementBy` version. If the desired element doesn't have an ID, you can use `.getElementsByClassName`, `.getElementsByTagName`, `.getElementsByName`, etc. However, an element is not a node.

Comment: no. All element nodes however do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element vs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: Just for whatever it's worth, those APIs are not "vanilla JavaScript", they're "vanilla web browser APIs". They're not part of the JavaScript language.

Comment: There are also exceptions, such as getElementById only being available on `document`.

Answer (score 7):

Principal element gathering *methods* from the **DOM API** are:

- `document.getElementById('[ID]')` *// returns live HTML Element Object*
- `document.getElementsByClassName('[CLASS]')` *// returns live HTML Collection Object*
- `document.getElementsByName('[NAME]')` *// returns live HTML Collection Object*
- `document.getElementsByTagName('[ELEMENT-TYPE]')` *// returns live
  HTML Collection Object*

and

- `document.querySelector('[CSS-SELECTOR]')` *// returns static HTML Element Object*
- `document.querySelectorAll('[CSS-SELECTOR]')` *// returns static NodeList Object*

Comment: [ELEMENT] should be [ID], [ELEMENT-TYPE] should be [TAGNAME] and [QUERY] should be [SELECTOR] (or [CSS-SELECTOR] if you prefer). querySelector() returns an Element just as getElementById() does, it does not return a single-element NodeList.

Comment: Thanks, @BoltClock. Well caught. I've updated all except TAGNAME, because I get acid reflux when I hear elements referred to as "tags".

Comment: But elements do have tag names.